# How to parse a string to a float, without the currency format?

Tags: c#, string

So i convert a float to a string, which is formatted as a currency.

```
float f = 2.99F;
string s = f.ToString("c2");
//s = 2.99 €
```

But when I want to convert it back to a float, it wouldn't be possible, because a float cant store the € symbol. So is there a way to convert the string back to a float, but it disregards the " €" (with the space)?

Comment: What you are doing is extremely risky; financial calculations are typically carried to a fixed number of decimal places and that is not how `float` calculations work; you probably should use `decimal` to represent monetary amounts. Also, `ToString("c2")` uses the machine localization; a user could change localizations so your "€2.99" could become "£2.99" or "$2.99". Is that what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
float f = 2.99F;
string s = f.ToString("c2");
var number = float.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol 
                           | NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work: `float f = 2.99F;
float.Parse(f.ToString("c2"), NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol);`

Comment: @Magnus it seems specifying the `NumberStyles.Currency` was necessary.now it works.

Comment: If you are dealing with money, are you **sure** you want `float` and not `decimal`? (This answers the question great, but for any future readers... PLEASE consider this)